# Location of cites using APA style format

Tags: citations, apa

If I write need to site a paragraph in APA style format, for example:

The quick brown fox jumped over the hill.

Do you put the citation in front of the sentence, at the end or at the bottom of the paper or a combination.

Answer (score 1):

In APA style, in-text citations are placed within sentences and paragraphs so that it is clear what information is being quoted or paraphrased and whose information is being cited.

Examples:

> Works by a single author

The last name of the author and the year of publication are inserted in the text at the appropriate point.

from theory on bounded rationality (Simon, 1945)

If the name of the author or the date appear as part of the narrative, cite only missing information in parentheses.

Simon (1945) posited that

Comment: You can view this link for more details.http://www.library.cornell.edu/resrch/citmanage/apa